# 2FA using firebase in android java project

Tags: firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I am developing a 2FA (SMS multi-factor authentication) using firebase android java project.
login page with email id and password and signup page. i am successfully completed the enrollment process for MFA. i got email also.

Now , i want to try login page for signing in with email id and password.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .addOnCompleteListener(
      new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          // User is not enrolled with a second factor and is successfully
          // signed in.
          // ...
          return;
        }
```

In the above code, i am done with no issue. But in the below code, I want to open the new java activity page to enter the OTP in Edit text and button and necessary permissions. I want to send SMS (otp) in next activity. How do I achieve this?

```
if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException) {
  FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException e =
    (FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException) task.getException();

  MultiFactorResolver multiFactorResolver = e.getResolver();

  // Ask user which second factor to use.
  MultiFactorInfo selectedHint =
    multiFactorResolver.getHints(). get(selectedIndex)
```

}
}

Comment: Anyone have answer to help me????

Comment: Please no need to answer. I will solved  myself. Because in stackoverflow only time waste. I pass this information to Everyone  No reply expected from buff frankin .there is time wasted on this site. So move on or think your problem and solve it